# Uploading videos using Youtube Data API v3

Tags: python, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have a small issue:
When trying to upload a video using the YouTube data API with Python, the video is automatically turned private and become locked when the upload finishes.

Is there any solution for this problem?

Comment: If I remember correctly this is a well-known issue, search StackOverflow and you'll find very similar questions.

Comment: It happens by design. You can try third-party extensions to circumvent the issue, e.g. https://github.com/linouk23/youtube_uploader_selenium

Comment: @AliceMyers no absolutely not don't tell people to circumvent google security measures by recommending third party Tools.   This statement is also wrong as it can be fixed in settings

Comment: @DaImTo Do you have any idea about this problem ?

Comment: @AimenZer was my answer not clear?  I have updated it to give you a bit more context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the very top of the documentation page for [videos.insert](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert) it states.

[image]

If you application is in testing mode videos are private.

Go to google cloud console for your project under the oauth2 screen.  Set it to public your videos will now upload as public or private

[image]